# Automatic variable selection algorithm in R: dealing with factor variable

Tags: r, algorithm, linear-regression, feature-selection

I would like to reduce a linear model through an automatic algorithm whose rule is based on p-values of the t-test for each coefficient. The problem arises when I include a categorical variable and its interactions with other predictors. Below you can find two example on a modfied version of `mtcars` dataset. Both use my algorithm: the first one does not include categorical variable and everything works smoothly. The second one has the variable `am` cast as a factor and the algorithm fails. It goes into an infinite loop.

**select_variables.lm() function:**

```
select_variables.lm = function( model, data, pval = 0.05 ) {

  cat( "---\n" )
  message( "pval threshold set to: ", pval )
  cat( "---\n" )
  max = max( summary( model )$coefficients[ 
    2:nrow( summary( model )$coefficients ), 4 ] )
  if ( pval > max ) {
    stop( "pval is too high to start" )
  }
  to_delete = names( which.max( summary( model )$coefficients[
    2:nrow( summary( model )$coefficients ), 4 ] ) )
  mod = update( model, paste0( "~ . - ", to_delete ), evaluate = FALSE )
  mod = eval.parent( mod )

  while ( max > pval ) {
    max = max( summary( mod )$coefficients[
      2:nrow( summary( mod )$coefficients ), 4 ] )
    to_delete = names( which.max( summary( mod )$coefficients[ 
      2:nrow( summary( mod )$coefficients ), 4 ] ) )
    mod = update( mod, paste0( "~ . - ", to_delete ), evaluate = FALSE )
    mod = eval.parent( mod )

    cat( "deleting", to_delete, "with a pval of:", max, "\n" )
  }
  return( invisible( mod ) )
}
```

**Example 1:**

```
# saving the data
data_no_factors = mtcars

# building a silly model
model1 = lm( hp ~ qsec + cyl + mpg + disp + drat + wt + qsec + vs
             + am + gear + carb + am:qsec, data = data_no_factors )
summary( model1 )

# reducing the silly model
model1_reduced = select_variables.lm( model1, data = data_no_factors )
summary( model1_reduced )
```

**Example 2:**

```
# saving the data and converting am to a factor
data_factor = mtcars
data_factor$am = as.factor( data_factor$am )
levels( data_factor$am ) = c( "no", "yes" )

# building another silly model
model2 = lm( hp ~ qsec + cyl + mpg + disp + drat + wt + qsec + vs
             + am + gear + carb + am:qsec, data = data_factor )
summary( model2 )

# reducing the new silly model: this will cause an infinite loop
model2_reduced = select_variables.lm( model2, data = data_factors )
summary( model2_reduced )
```

Hoping the question is well posed, any hints will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do convert to factor if you are doing regression? Wouldn't an integer value for $am be better?

Comment: @Ansjovis86 provided the fact that `am` is clearly an integer, this is just an example which makes my algorithm fail. I know that integer conversion is a good practice, but I need to have some clinical variables expressed as classes. They cannot be converted then. Using `am` as a factor mimics my specific case. Thanks anyway for the suggestion

Comment: but if you keep it as a factor regression will fail in my experience

Comment: @Ansjovis86 this is a wrong statement. Multivariate regression allows for the inclusion of categorical predictor. Think about the gender of a subject.